# d3 area chart filling below x asis

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to draw area graph but it is filling below x axis. In below code I have used y0(yScale(0)) as I have seen in many examples and also I tried to give y0(height) it is not giving me correct output. I want area to be filled only above x axis if y axis values are +ve and if y axis values are -ve then area is going above max tick of y axis.

```
const D3Node = require('d3-node');

getGraphString: (data,yAxisTickFormat) => {
    const d3n = new D3Node() // initializes D3 with container element
    const d3 = d3n.d3;

    let margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 40 },
      width = 275,
      height = 200;

    let svg = d3n.createSVG(width, height+margin.top+margin.bottom);
    let xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date })), 
    yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top, margin.bottom])
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.value }));
  
    svg.append('g').attr("class", "xAxis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")") //The transforms are SVG transforms
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeYear).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y')))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor","end")
      .attr("dx", "-.9em")
      .attr("dy", ".50em")
      .attr("transform","rotate(-45)")

    svg.append("g") //We create an SVG Group Element to hold all the elements that the axis function produces.
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + ",0)")
      .attr("class","yAxis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(4).tickFormat(d3.format(yAxisTickFormat)))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor","end")
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("dx", "-0.4em")

    let lineFunc = d3.line().x(function (obj) { return xScale(obj.date) })
      .y(function (obj) { return yScale(obj.value) })
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", lineFunc(data))
      .attr("stroke", '#002046')
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .attr("fill", "none");
    
    let area = d3.area()
      .curve(d3.curveLinear)
      .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.date); })
      .y0(yScale(0))
      .y1(function (d) { return yScale(d.value); });

    svg.append("path")
      .style("fill", "#002046")
      .attr("d", area(data));
    return d3n.svgString();
  }
    let data =[ { date: 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, value: 0.6330419130189774 },
  { date: 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, value: 0.6266752649582236 },
  { date: 2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, value: 0.6403446517126394 },
  { date: 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, value: 0.6432956408788177 } ];
getGraphString(data,'.0%');
```

[image: area graph]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

If your y axis (scale domain) starts at 0, then `yScale(0)` is an appropriate baseline for the area. However, your scale's domain extent does not start at 0, it is dependent on the dataset:

```
 yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top, margin.bottom])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.value }));
```

The lowest value in your dataset is `0.6266...` not zero. In using `yScale(0)` D3 interpolates where `y(0)` would be, which in your case would require extending the axis quite a bit down the page and off the SVG.

**Solution**

We can manually set the baseline with something like : `area.y0(yScale(0.6266...))`. This places the baseline at the base of your y axis. But you don't need to set it manually as you can can set it with:

```
 area.y0(yScale.range()[0]);
```

yScale.range() returns an array containing the scaled extent of the yScale (and therefore the y axis), we want to have the area's base be the same as the axis.

*`yScale.range()[0]` is the equivilant of `yScale(yScale.domain()[0]);` - if 0 is the minimum value of the domain (`0 == yScale.domain()[0]`), it's a short jump to the often used `area.y0(yScale(0))`*

**Alternative**

Alternatively, if you want the axis to include zero, you could keep `yScale(0)` as the baseline and set 0 to be the minimum value of the scale's domain:

```
 .domain([0,d3.max(function(d) { return d.value; })])
```

Either way, the value provided as the minimum value for the scale's range and area.y0 should be the same if you want the bottom of the area to be aligned to the bottom of the axis. (This value should generally also be equal to the y translate value for the x axis).

Comment: Yes this worked. But if I have only -ve values on y axis I am getting chart area filled below line in graph instead of above area of line.

Comment: Hi Andrew,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048007/how-to-reset-the-d3-selection-of-point

Can you help me with this query ? it's new question.